# How to get array of subelements from an element?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

My xml looks likes this

```xml
<stock name="Fish">
    <eqn>100</eqn>
    <inflow>Spawns</inflow>
    <outflow>Deaths</outflow>
    <outflow>Flow_1</outflow>
    <non_negative/>
</stock>
```

My code looks likes this

```cs
var stockList = from q in variable.Descendants(ns + "stock")
select new {
    name = q.FirstAttribute.Value,
   initial = q.Element(ns + "eqn").Value,
   inflow = q.Element(ns + "inflow").Value,
   outflow = q.Element(ns + "outflow").Value
};
```

This only gives me the first inflow and first outflow, but there are two outflows so I need to be store each one in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`public IEnumerable<XElement> Elements (XName name)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Elements_System_Xml_Linq_XName_). It returns all the child elements of this element having a matching name.

```
outflow = q.Elements(ns + "outflow").Select(el => el.Value).ToArray()
```

or

```
outflow = (from el in q.Elements(ns + "outflow") select el.Value).ToArray()
```